# Angular filter for last element

Tags: angular, angular-filters

How can I write a filter , which only returns the last element of a list / how can I write a filter which returns all but the last element.

Background:
I'm having a list of items, where the last item should be editable. Therefor I need this filter to get it.

Comment: It appears that this is using a pre-release (Alpha) version of Angular. Angular is now on version 4.3.1. It changed *significantly* from the pre-release to the final release. I'd highly recommend upgrading to at least the released version of Angular. Otherwise any code you find/try to use won't work in your application. (For example, alpha 44 did not have Angular modules, which are now a key feature of Angular.)

Comment: @DebrorahK the code is only what I found on this issue, I'm working with the latest version :)

Comment: Good to hear. Note that the ngFor syntax also changed quite a bit from this code. So it may make sense to start from scratch and not try to use this code. Can you post what *your* filter code looks like so far?

Comment: I just want to filter for the last element, I have no other filter code. And I want to avoid rewriting an existing feature

Comment: The short answer to your question is to use an Observable operator, such as the `Last` operator shown here: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/last.html Without some idea of the code you are trying to use this in, it would be hard to provide an example of how to use it.

Comment: Or if you are working with an array, something like this: `let my_array = /* your array values */;
let last_element = my_array[my_array.length - 1];`

Comment: @DeborahK Am I missing the point of the question? I thought he was asking how to display part of a list - would a pipe [like in this example I made](https://plnkr.co/edit/lEVQJ0RHQLFN98iVCxmd?p=preview) not be sufficient?

Comment: Yea, it was difficult to get the exact context looking only at an old example the OP found. So it looks like you are using the array technique I posted but flushed it out for him. You should move your comment into the answer because that should do it for him. :-)

Comment: @0mpurdy your example is perfect, if you post it as answer, I accept it :)

Comment: @Stefan you may want to edit the tags on your question also - you have said in your comments that you are using Angular 2, but you have tagged it as `angularjs` the correct tag is `angular`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [`Pipe`](https://angular.io/guide/pipes) to filter an array

**pipe**

```js
@Pipe({name: 'lastItem'})
export class LastItemPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[], exclusive: boolean): any {
    if (exclusive) { return items.slice(0, items.length - 1); }
    return [items[items.length - 1]];
  }
}
```

**template**

```html
<h2>list without</h2>    
<div *ngFor="let item of items | lastItem:true">{{item}}</div>    
<h2>list with</h2>    
<div *ngFor="let item of items | lastItem:false">{{item}}</div>
```

[Live plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:2evIsom7MHzyaRFJpQX3)